# Can I somehow remove the animation from buttons generated by addthis.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using addthis.com to generate social media share buttons, however, their buttons come with an animation on hover which I really don't like and would like to remove it if possible.

You can see the issue live here - http://onyx.space/image/4

The problem is that the only code I've been given is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5b50a10e742393c0"></script>
```

And the code for the buttons:

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
```

There is some customization on their website, however, there's nothing about animations. I've googled this issue and found nothing about it.

I wonder whether the animation comes from the JavaScript and how would I go about finding it and removing it.

Comment: add a style like this to your site: `.at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn:focus, .at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn:hover { transform: none !important; }`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Add it as answer if you like so I can select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override that animation with more specific selector. for example add below css code in your css file

```
div .at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn:focus, 
div .at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn:hover {
    transform: none;
}
```